# Setting image colorkey in processing 3.2

Tags: java, image-processing, processing

I'm trying to make a algorithm that will make all the pixels of a certain color in an image transparent. This is what I tried so far:

```
void setup() {
  PImage img;
  img = loadImage("img.png");
  if (color(img) == color(255) {
    alpha(img) = 0;
  }
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

But I get the error `The function color() expects paramters like "color(int)"` What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
PImage set_colorkey (PImage img, color colorkey) {
  PImage new_img = img.get();
  new_img.loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < new_img.width*new_img.height; i++) {
    if (new_img.pixels[i] == colorkey) {
      new_img.pixels[i] = color(255, 1);
    }
  }
  new_img.updatePixels();
  return new_img;
}

void setup() {
  background(255, 0, 0);
  PImage img = loadImage("img.png");
  img = set_colorkey(img, color(255));
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: But why the color(255, 1) in line 6?

Comment: Setting the transparency to 0 seems to mess with the system and make the color completely nontransparent.